# What was Jai's mistake in the past

Tags: curse-of-the-golden-flower

At the beginning of *Curse of the Golden Flower* when The Emperor and Prince Jai stop off in a building on their way to the palace, The Emperor tells Jai that he came to remind Jai of his mistake from the past and

> Never take by force what I don't give.

This seems as if this mistake the Emperor mentions is linked to Jai trying to take something that belonged to the Emperor but failed to do so and given how at the end of the film the Emperor was going to give Jai the Throne I get the feeling that this exchange was the Emperor reminding Jai not to try and take the throne again. However, I don't recall any mention of a previous rebellion by Jai.

So what was this mistake Prince Jai made in the past?